# Send jquery ajax post request with html array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to send an ajax request to a php page. I have had no problems for regular HTML field data, however I am unable to figure out the correct syntax to pass a html field by name, when the name is an array.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='selected[]' value='my value'>
```

There is several of these as they are generated dynamically.

I attempt to call it as such :

```
$.post('myProcess.php',{exportSelected:true,myValues:$("input[name='selected[]']").val()})
                .done(function(data){
                    console.log(data);              
});
```

This works perfectly fine if I pass it as a single value, eg selected without there []. I am unsure how to say "pass ALL the values of selected[] if they are checked"

I have found a couple examples of posting regular javascript arrays, however this does not seem to help in this case.

Comment: For multiple you have iterate using each function and store values in array. And then send those values as json string  or just array of selected values

Comment: As @Manjunath says use a loop to store the values e.g : var selected = $('input[name="selected[]"]').map((i,e)=>{
if(e.checked){
return e.value;
}
})
console.log(selected);